# How can I get Run as Administrator option back in Server 2012 context menu?

Tags: windows-server-2012, file-association

Somehow file associations .bat and .cmd (possibly .exe also) became associated with Notepad++ on Windows Server 2012. As a result, the "Run as Administrator" context menu option is NOT available for any files of these types.  None of the options shown in the article at https://kb.abacusprivatecloud.com/articles/488-How-To-Change-Default-Programs-Applications worked. I tried associating .bat with cmd.exe, but the system simply sat "grindging away" for quite a while, then the panel came back, but no change was made in association.

How can I reset these file types back to their default associations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently someone logged onto this server and dd something to correct the problem. The .bat file I had been trying to Run as Administrator, now has that option in the context menu. I have no idea who may have corrected the problem, but everything seems to be working as it should at the present time. Thanks for the response nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the Registry Editor by pressing `WinKey`+`R` and typing in `regedit`.
2. Navigate to the folder (key) `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\`.
3. Check if a key named `runas` exists under the `shell` key. If not, create the key by right-clicking on `shell` and clicking on *New* > *Key*. Call this key `runas`.
4. This next step is not possible in the `regedit` graphical interface. Open a command prompt window as an administrator and run this command:

   ```
   reg add HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\runas\command /ve /t REG_EXPAND_SZ
   ```
5. Back in the `regedit` window, go to the `batfile` key and press F5 (*View* > *Refresh*). You then should see the `command` key listed under the `runas` key.
6. Edit the `(Default)` value in the `runas\command` key to this value:

   ```
   %SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /C "%1" %*
   ```
7. For `cmd` files, run the same steps above for the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell` key.